# What function to use in getting all textbox names in form using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how can I get all the textbox names in a form using C#?

Here is my code in generating dynamically textboxes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            txtbox.Name = "txtbox" + i;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtbox);

            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "lbl" + i;
            lbl.Text = lbl.Name;
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] textBoxNamesArray = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                      .Select(r => r.Name)
                                      .ToArray();

        var textboxes = string.Join(",", textBoxNamesArray);

        MessageBox.Show(textboxes);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ to get all the names of the controls of type `TextBox` from the current form. The following query will return you an array of strings containing all the names.

```
string[] textBoxNamesArray = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                          .Select(r => r.Name)
                                          .ToArray();
```

Remember to include `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks, I'll tries this.. :)

Comment: Hey, Why it is blank on the messagebox? :)

Comment: @GrayFullBuster, My bad. instead of `this.Controls` use `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls` since you are adding textbox to `flowLayoutPanel1`.  I missed that part

Comment: any other answer without LINQ statement

Comment: @VikasKunte, using a simple loop one can do that. Something like           `foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control is TextBox)
                    listOfArrayNames.Add(control.Name);
            }`

Answer (score 2):

I used this.controls . You can convert or add it.

```
for ( int x = 0; x < i; x++ )
            {
                TextBox txtbox= ( TextBox )this.Controls["txtbox" + ( x + 1 ).ToString()];
               double commissions = Convert.ToDouble( txtbox.Text ) / 100;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use .NET 4.0 with LINQ you can use the following code

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(control.Controls);
var names = list.ToArray()
            .Where(src => src is TextBox)
            .Select(src => (src as TextBox).Name);
```

The Method which is provided by Habib is a little bit better ;)